# Replace a line containing special characters in all files recursively using SED MAC

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, mac, sed

I was trying to replace a line with another using `SED` on `MAC OS X Terminal`
I have a scenario where I need to replace a line in all files present in a directory with another line. 
Both lines are complex and have different special characters and symbols.

How can I replace it?

I need to replace

```
import { wait } from 'path/and-child-path'
```

with

```
import { wait } from 'path/path/and-child-path'
```

What I was trying is

```
find . -type f | xargs sed -i '' "s@import { wait } from 'path/and-child-path'@import { wait } from 'path/and-child-path'@g"
```

This doesn't work. Please help me out.

Comment: Your explanation and command do not match.

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk I think the command `sed` is according to explanation. In case the command is not matching, you can refer some better alternative. Thanks

Comment: Your `sed` script works, but there is an extra `''` before the actual script, so `sed` is trying to run the commands inside `''`. If you want a backup file, is `-i.old`. And you forgot to put the right replacement text in the `s///` command. Try this `sed -i "s@import { wait } from 'path/and-child-path'@import { wait } from 'path/path/and-child-path'@g"`

Answer (score 0):

The `sed` you provided has the very same match and replace pattern (in case that was not a typo), so you can't expect any change in the files. Besides the `''` bit should not be there.

Correcting those points, you *would* end up with

```
find . -type f | xargs sed -i \
"s@import { wait } from 'path/and-child-path'@import { wait } from 'path/path/and-child-path'@g"
```

**That code will nonetheless fail** in the general case, because filenames may contain space (and even newline!) characters, which is exactly what `xargs` uses as delimiters. So if you have the file `A X`, `sed` would be instructed to act on files `A` and `X`.

`-exec` option solves the problem straightforwardly:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec sed -i \
"s@import { wait } from 'path/and-child-path'@import { wait } from 'path/path/and-child-path'@g" {} +
```

Notice I have also added `-maxdepth 1`, otherwise `find` would descend into subdirectories too.